# ASP.NET Can not Change Visibility of a Formview control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events, formview

I feel this is stupid, but what the hell...

this is two lines of a methods that handles a dropdownlist event:

```
        resolve = (Button)FormView1.FindControl("btn_resolve");
        resolve.Visible = true;
```

It used to work with me earlier! Not working now

Comment: How is it not working?  As a side issue, I tend to wrap my actions on a control that I have found with FindControl in an if not foundControl is nothing block...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use formview Databound event like

```
 protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        btn_resolve = (Button)FormView1.FindControl("btn_resolve");
        resolve.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mo,
I just that by adding a databound event to formview and also changed the if statement according to my algorithm