# using FormView to insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, formview

I have a formview control, and on the `ItemCreated` event, I am "priming" some of the fields with default values.

However, when I try to use the formview to insert, before the `ItemInserting` event gets called, for some reason it calls `ItemCreated` first.  That results in the fields being over-written with the default values right before the insert happens.

How do I get it to not call the `ItemCreated` event before the `ItemInserting` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use formview Databound event instead of formview ItemCreated event to set values, try like

```
protected void frm_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frm.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)//whatever your mode here is.
    {
        TextBox txtYourTextBox = (TextBox)frm.FindControl("txtYourTextBox");
        txtYourTextBox.Text// you can set here your Default value
    }
}
```

Also check this thread of similare issue
[FormView_Load being overwritten C# ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574860/formviewload-being-overwritten-c-asp-net/1576174#1576174)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the order in which the events fire. However, you should probably wrap the code that sets the default values inside `!IsPostBack` so that it doesn't reset your values for example:

```
protected void FormView_ItemCreated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
    //Set default values ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work because when I actually do want to hit the ItemCreated, it is on a postback.

Comment: In that case, you may have to add an If statement checking whether there's a value before setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the [CurrentMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode%28VS.80%29.aspx) property of the form view.

```
void FormView_ItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormView.CurrentMode != FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        //Initialize your default values here
    }
}
```